# No route found for GET /block-render?_format=xml

Tags: blocks, 8

I have installed render-block 8.x-1.0-alpha1 module in drupal 8 and i try to get all blocks like this:

`http://localhost/drupal8/block-render?_format=xml`

But i get this message error:

```
<response>
    <message>No route found for "GET /block-render"</message>
</response>
```

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed RestUI module and configured the REST resources for Block Render

admin -> config -> SERVICES WEB -> Rest

and it works now !